# How to get value of a text box in a dialog box using jquery in php, i get it as blank or undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How to get value of a text box in a dialog box using jquery in php. I am opening a dialog box on click of  button in which there is a text box as comments. I want this value to submit to the database. But the value i get is undefined or blank when i alert it. I am unable to get the message value of the textbox. My Code is as:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".QTPopup").css('display','none');
$(".lnchPopop").click(function(){
    $(".QTPopup").animate({width: 'show'}, 'slow');});
    $(".closeBtn").click(function(){            
        $(".QTPopup").css('display', 'none');
    });                   
$(document).on('click','.submit_comment',function(){
    alert("Hello");
    var comments=$('#comment_by_user').val();
    alert(comments);
    var comments1= document.getElementById("comment_by_user").value;
    alert(comments1); 
    });
});
</script>
```

The Dialog box opens on the click of the Comment Hyperlink.

```
a href="#" class="lnchPopop">Comments</a>
<div class="QTPopup" style="display: none">
<div class="QTPopupCntnr">                                                                                                             
<div class="gpBdrLeftTop"></div>                                                                                                
<div class="gpBdrRightTop"></div>                                                                                                
<div class="gpBdrTop"></div>                                                                                              
<div class="gpBdrLeft">                                                                                                       
<div class="gpBdrRight">                                                                                                             
<div class="caption">                                                                                                          
Send Your Messages                                                                                                       
</div>                                                                                                       
<a href="#" class="closeBtn" title="Close"></a>                                                                                                            
<div class="content">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
<br />                                                                                                                   
<table>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
<tr>                                                                                                                                
<td style="height:5px;"></td>                                                                                                                         
</tr>                                                                                                                             
<tr>                                                                                                                                    
<td>&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                            
</tr>                                                                                                                             
<tr>                                                                                                                                      
<td>                                                                                                                                             
<textarea class="textareagradiant" id="comment_by_user" name="comment_by_user" 
style="width:428px; height:116px; border:1px solid #CFCECE;"> </textarea>                                                                                                                                      
</td>                                                                                                                          
</tr>                                                                                                                            
<tr>                                                                                                                                      
<td style="height:5px;"></td>                                                                                                                           
</tr>                                                                                                                            
<tr>                                                                                                                                 
<td style="height:10px;"></td>                                                                                                                          
</tr>                                                                                                                         
<tr>                                                                                                                                    
<td>                                                                                                                                    
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="gbtn_s submit_comment"  />                                                                                                                                     
<input type="button" value="Reset" class="gbtn_s"  />                                                                                                                                     
</td>                                                                                                                             
</tr>                                                                                                                    
</table>                                                                                                              
</div>                                                                                                   
</div>                                                                                            
</div>                                                                                         
<div class="gpBdrLeftBottom"></div>                                                                                            
<div class="gpBdrRightBottom"></div>                                                                                        
<div class="gpBdrBottom"></div
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: too many codes. please post codes only relative to the problem

Comment: just check your console errors if any and tells us the error...@Aaron

Comment: @SmartKiller There are no errors in the console log.

Comment: just add any class in textbox and try to get value using class like $('.your_class').val(); @Aaron17a

Comment: @SmartKiller I have tried it adding class and get the value but still it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the alert("Hello");

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".QTPopup").css('display','none');
$(".lnchPopop").click(function(){
    $(".QTPopup").animate({width: 'show'}, 'slow');});
    $(".closeBtn").click(function(){            
        $(".QTPopup").css('display', 'none');
    });                   
$(document).on('click','.submit_comment',function(){

    var comments=$('#comment_by_user').val();
    alert(comments);
    var comments1= document.getElementById("comment_by_user").value;
    alert(comments1); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine. Make sure you correct the first line

`<a href="#" class="lnchPopop">Comments</a>`

A working copy can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/6LXSn/1/.

To get the value to php I usualy use a jQuery AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'your php script',
    data: {
                comments: comments
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    async: false,
    error: function(obj, text, error) {
    },
    success: function(response) {
    }
});
```

then retrieve your comments value in php as

```
$_POST['comments']
```

hope this helps

Comment: Still the same problem, Can there be a problem of jquery version i am using, which version should i use.

Comment: Try getting the value as you can see in my example `var comments=$('#comment_by_user').val();`. I tried with older versions of jQuery and seems to be working fine with 1.7.2 and later.